# Await not returning result inspite of success in api call - Typescript

Tags: typescript, async-await

```
 if (imageFile !== undefined) {
  s3Url = await uploadImage(imageFile, user.user_id);
}
```

---

```
 const uploadImage = async (attachment: IAttachment, userId: string) => {
  if (!attachment) {
    return '';
  }

  // attempting to upload image to S3
  try {
    await upload({
      file: attachment.file,
      fileName: attachment.fileName,
      userId,
    })
      .then((s3Url) => {
        return s3Url;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        return Promise.reject(e);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
};
```

awaits the result as seen below:

[image]

However when the result is returned

[image]

response:

[image]

Comment: looks like the response of KBFetch isn't working as intended, can you show what output the response is?

Comment: @Zer0 Added it seems to be coming

Comment: `.then((s3Url) => { return s3Url; }).catch((e) => { return Promise.reject(e); });` does nothing and can be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `uploadImage` is not returning anything:

```
// Promise is handled but not returned.
await upload({
    file: attachment.file,
    fileName: attachment.fileName,
    userId,
  })
    .then((s3Url) => {
      // This value is lost.
      return s3Url;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    });
```

First I would refactor `uploadImage` to only use `async/await`:

```
const uploadImage = async (attachment: IAttachment, userId: string) => {
  if (!attachment) {
    return '';
  }

  // I removed try/catch block because the error was rethrown without modification.
  const s3Url = await upload({
    file: attachment.file,
    fileName: attachment.fileName,
    userId,
  })
   
  return s3Url;
};
```

Now you see that a value is returned and you shouldn't get `unedfined` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for this not sure how dumb I was to miss that

Comment: Ahah no worries. Maybe a cup of coffee could help ;)